# python file list search (I have two matching strings but python doesn't think they are equal)

Tags: python, file, list, split

if your input is john why isn't the if statement kicking in????

```
studentname.txt

john 34
paul 37
poop 45
```

above is whats in studentname.txt

```
b=a
name = input('students name : ')
list1=[]

file=open('studentname.txt','r')
for (a) in file:
    list1.append(a)    
    b=a[:-3]
```

why isn't this next if statement tripping if name entered is 'john' for instance??

```
    if name == b:
        print(a)

file.close
```

Comment: also in studentname.txt there are no ### before the name and number

Comment: Try printing `b` regardless to see if it really is what you expect. Also, you may try `split` instead of using the substring syntax since that would be more reliable (if there was ever a number that wasn't two digits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are picking up newlines. Depending on the os you created the file on, you'll have different new line characters. The safest way to rid yourself of this is:

```
a = a.rstrip()
```

That will take care of any trailing whitespace.

You could also do:

```
for a in map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), file):
```

Also, don't name your variable 'file'. This is a python built-in function that you've now renamed for your script and any script that imports it.

Finally, you might prefer to handle files like this:

```
with open("studentname.txt", 'r') as testfile:
    for item in (line.rstrip() for line in testfile):
        print item
```

No need to close the file, the with statement controls it's scope and closes it.

Comment: -1 (1) Use mode='rU' to overcome the problem of reading Windows-created text files on Unixy OSs (2) line.strip() is unsafe/overkill/butchery; line.rstrip('\n') is what is required.

Comment: @JohnMachin : so much downvotes are fairly unusual in SO for such a simple question, specially if the downvoter didn't even care to post his own answer.

Comment: thanks! for now a = a.rstrip() is the easiest to understand. My search works now.

Comment: Great to hear, gratholio! Remember to mark the best answer and happy coding!

Comment: Not my favorite, but it's a good building block to my final recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use `a.strip()[:-3]`, which will trim all whitespace characters before taking the substring.

Comment: -1 The LAST line in a file does not necessarily end in `\n`. `a[:-4]` at best conflates the data-specific some_field[:-3] issue with the transport mechanism issue and at worst will omit a data byte. Also `a.strip()` is butchery -- see my comment on another answer.

Comment: Your comment on another answer is "`a.strip()` is butchery" Care to elaborate at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for a in file.readlines():
    name, _, score = a.strip().partition(' ')
    if name == b:
        print(a)
```

It is cleaner in that it doesn't rely on a 2-digit value and is more expressive than arbitrary indexes. It also strips carriage returns and newlines.

Comment: -1 (1) Using readlines is preposterous. `for a in file` does the same thing without building a list of all lines. (2) a.strip() is butchery. (3) The only way you would get CRs is by reading a Windows text file on Unix; if you fear that, use mode='rU' for universal newlines.

Comment: Good point on the readlines. I don't think there's anything wrong with strip here, though, obviously depending on the specific application. More often than not, for user-editable files, I prefer stripping all leading and trailing whitespace. If this was a data file where leading spaces were important, then obviously this would not be a good place for strip.

Comment: Removing leading & trailing whitespace, and replacing whitespace runs by a single space, is a good thing to do to each TEXT FIELD; this makes line.(|l|r)strip() of no use. Doing other than line.rstrip('\n') is a bad habit to get into. It butchers any significant whitespace e.g. tabs.

Answer (score -3):

Your immediate problem is as others have mentioned that you are not aware of the `\n` at the end of your data. `print` and the `repr` built-in function are your friends; use them:

```
if name != b:
    print repr(name), repr(b)
```

whereupon the cause of the problem becomes obvious.

Here is some (untested) code that illustrates better practice when handling simple data file formats like yours. It is intended to cope with blank/empty lines, unterminated last line, and real-life possibilities like:

```
Jack 9
Jill 100
Billy Bob 99
Decimus 1.23
Numberless
```

without crashing or running amok.

```
with open('studentname.txt','rU') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        fields = line.split()
        nf = len(fields]
        if nf == 0: 
            continue: # blank/empty line
        if nf == 1:
            print('Only 1 field in line', line_number, repr(line))
            continue
        dataname = ' '.join(fields[:-1])
        try:
            datanumber = int(fields[-1])
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid number', repr(fields[-1]), 'in line',
                line_number, repr(line))
            continue
    list1.append((dataname, datanumber))   
    if name == dataname:
        print(repr(dataname), number)
```

Note `file.close` evaluates to a method/function object, which does nothing. You need to call it: `file.close()`. However now that you are using the `with` statement, it will look after closing the file, so just delete that `file.close` line.

Comment: -1 Answer and sample listing are beyond the scope of question